# Swift - Creating parameters object

Tags: json, swift

I have an issue with creating an parameters object for alamofire.
Some of the String keys do not have the ""´s as well as some of the string values.

Can you guys tell me what i am doing wrong?

provider_user_id
provider_uid

device->
dpi
name
os

maker->
name

Can someone explain to me why:

```
func callFineBackend(provider_uid:String!,provider_user_id:String!) -> String{
    print("get token and post")

    let screen = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let res_x = Int(screen.width)
    let res_y = Int(screen.height)
    let devicename = String(UIDevice.currentDevice().name)
    let os = String(UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion)
    let mem_mb = Double(NSProcessInfo.processInfo().physicalMemory)
    let provider_name = "facebook"
    let dpi = 126


    let xlatGPS = 34.951231
    let xlonGPS = 43.714323
    let stringLat = String(xlatGPS)
    let stringLon = String(xlonGPS)

    let headers: [String: String] = [
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        "X-Latitude": stringLat,
        "X-Longitude": stringLon
    ]

    let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [

        "maker": [
            "name": "Apple"
        ],
        "device": [
            "name": devicename,
            "mem_mb": mem_mb,
            "dpi": dpi,
            "res_x": res_x,
            "rex_y": res_y,
            "os": os
        ],
        "provider_name": provider_name,
        "provider_user_id": provider_user_id,
        "provider_uid": provider_uid,
    ]

    print(parameters)
```

Turns into:

```
    [
  "provider_user_id": 12315123512, "device": {
    dpi = 126;
    "mem_mb" = 4294967296;
    name = "iPhone Simulator";
    os = "9.3";
    "res_x" = 320;
    "rex_y" = 480;
}, "provider_uid": EAAX, 
"maker": {
    name = Apple;
}, "provider_name": facebook
]
```

Comment: Because print behaves this way! Send the data to the server and you will see that the dictionary *hopefully* arrives correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with what's printed.

When printing a `NSDictionary`, strings are surrounded by quotes only if they contain a character that is not a letter or number.

In this case, `parameters` is of type `Dictionary`,
but `parameters["maker"]`, `parameters["device"]`, etc are of type `NSDictionary`.